# How to add color to a sibling text using custom directive in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am learning angular 4 , I am practice custom directive , what I am trying to do is to change the color of the text border on selecting any option from select, means if option selected is red then change the border to red. blue then blue . Like below :

[image]

Below is my directive class :

```
import {Directive , ElementRef, Renderer, OnInit} from'@angular/core'
@Directive({
selector : "[dirNew]"
})
export class dirNew{
constructor ( private _el : ElementRef, private ren : Renderer){
//  ren.setElementStyle(private _ 
el.nativeElement.parentElement,"background","solid 2px red");
}
ngOnInit() {
//console.log(this._el.nativeElement.parentElement);   

this.ren.setElementStyle(this._el.nativeElement.parentElement,
"background","solid 2px red");
}
}
```

Below is my component class :

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
selector:"dir-app",
templateUrl:"drComp.html"
})

export class dirComp{
arrName =[1,2,3];
colors = ["red","blue","pink"];
}
```

Below is my html for the directive usage :

```
<div *ngFor="let arr of arrName">{{arr}}
<input type ="text">
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let cl of colors" dirNew>{{cl}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call function in your Directive when where option is selected.

.html

```
<select (change)="OnChange($event);">
<option *ngFor="let cl of colors" dirNew>{{cl}}</option>
</select>
```

.ts

```
import { dirNew } from './app-directive.component';
....

export class appComponent {
    @ViewChild('dirNew') dirV;

    OnChange(event: any){
        this.dirV.OnChangeSelect(event.target.value)
    }
}
```

directive.ts

```
import {Directive , ElementRef, Renderer, OnInit} from'@angular/core'

@Directive({
selector : "[dirNew]"
})

export class dirNew{
  .....
  .....
  .....

  OnChangeSelect(color: any){

   this.ren.setElementStyle(this._el.nativeElement.parentElement,
    "background",color);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your required directive:

**Steps/Explanation:**

> 1. I created a directive which takes input color and changes the border
> 2. I used `@Input('myColor') myColor: string;` to receive color from
>      the directive from HTML
> 3. I added `ngModel` to select and added `[myColor]="color"` in  HTML
> 4. I used ngOnChnages to detect color changes and respective border
>      color will be changed
> 5. Finally I used `this.el.nativeElement.style.border` and used the
>      color from input to change the border color Dynamically.

**Code:**

**Directive:**

```
import {  Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, Renderer, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[myColor]' })

export class colorDirective {
    @Input('myColor') myColor: string;

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['myColor']) {
      console.log(changes['myColor'])
      if(changes['myColor'].previousValue != changes['myColor'].currentValue){
         this.highlight(changes['myColor'].currentValue);
      }
    }
  }

    constructor(public el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
           this.highlight(this.myColor);
    }

    private highlight(color: string) {
       this.el.nativeElement.style.border = '3px solid '+ color;
       }
}
```

**Use it in HTML as:**

```
<input type ="text" [myColor]="color">
<select [(ngModel)]="color" (change)="change()">
    <option *ngFor="let cl of colors" dirNew>{{cl}}</option>
</select>
```

[**Here is a Working DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-9wsggv?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

---

**Update: Without a Directive working in a Loop too:**

**Code:**

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div class="container">
<div *ngFor="let arr of arrName">
<input type ="text" [ngStyle]="getStyle(arr)">
<select [(ngModel)]="newobject[arr]">
    <option *ngFor="let cl of colors" dirNew>{{cl}}</option>
</select>
</div>

  </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  newobject = {};
  arrName =[1,2,3];
  colors = ["red","blue","pink"];

   getStyle(value){
      if(this.newobject[value]){
       return {"border": "2px solid "+this.newobject[value]};
     }
   }
}
```

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-k7o9z2?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: @yepMe, have you checked this? any help needed?

Comment: Sravan . Thanks like this it works but on creating three divs of same type , it applies the same color to all three due o [(ngModel)] and removing it doesn't work

Comment: @yepMe, added that solution too. Please check once.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help , it works, but actually I wanted to learn custom directive, wanted to apply it using custom directive, but your code is only using component ?? Could we do it using custom directives?

Comment: Yeah the first answer is using the directive.